# Was Schottky right with the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2+r^2 x^2}\;dx$

Tags: integration

The famous German physicist Walter Schottky (1986-1976), in a publication on "thermal agitation of electricity in conductors" in the 1920ies, calculated the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2+r^2 x^2}\;dx$ to be $\frac{2\pi}{r^2}$. This gave rise to a critical remark of a colleague. Can you guess why?

Hint: this is a math question.

Comment: This seems more to be a riddle or a puzzle than a question about mathematics.

Comment: And leave it to a physicist to be $-10$ years old....

Comment: This question is not formulated in the way this website is meant to work. And also the $r$ is unspecified. Is it real, complex, positive real, negative? Can it be $0$? You cannot properly write down a 1-parameter integral without this information.

Comment: Maybe because the given value is wrong?

Comment: Dimensional analysis alone tells us this is wrong. It's actually $\frac{\pi}{2r}$ (if $r>0$), as is easily proven with e.g. [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem).

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the hint to GMT

Comment: @J.G.  Sounds good at first, but how would you actually perform dimensional analysis here? It should work also if we replace the term $(1-x^2)$ by $(1+x^2)$ but here the integral is different from 1/r. Hence dimensional analysis alone is not enough.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Well-spotted: you've shown (i) I must have used GMT before DA & (ii) GMT can't replace $x+1/x$ with $x$ the same way it can $x-1/x$.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a math question about an improper integral with answer $\dfrac{\pi}{2 r}.$ Therefore Mr Schottky’s answer is wrong. I have a wonderful trick to handle the integral for $0<r<2$. $$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{2}+r^{2} x^{2}} d x \quad \textrm{, where }0<r<2.\\
=& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{4}+\left(r^{2}-2\right) x^{2}+1} d x\\
=& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\left(r^{2}-2\right)} d x \\
=& \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\left(r^{2}-2\right)} d x \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}+r^{2}}-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}-\left(4-r^{2}\right)}\right] \\
=& \frac{1}{2 r}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{r}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{4-r^{2}}}\left[\ln \left| \frac{x+\frac{1}{x}-\sqrt{4-r^{2}}}{\left.x+\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{4-r^{2}}\right)}\right|\right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
=& \frac{\pi}{2 r}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

In the special case of $r=2$, the integral satisfies the inequity
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{2}+r^{2} x^{2}} d x 
\overset {r=2}=
 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}} d x 
< \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} d x= \frac\pi2
\end{align}
while the stated result gives the impossible value $\frac{2\pi}{r^2} \overset {r=2}=\frac\pi2$, which is the source of the critical remark.